# Call Java Native Interface from web application

Tags: java, jsf-2, jboss, ear, war

I have a question about how to develop a web application which can call C functions using Java Native Interface (JNI).
  My biggest question is what king of package do I need in order JNI to work: WAR package or EAR package deployed on JBoss 7 server? Is there any difference in this case?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any package, but you will probably need a good understanding of Classloading (particularly with JBOSS) and what happens when Class Loaders load native libraries.  I suggest you start with the [JBOSS Classloader Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Developer+Guide).

Answer (score 2):

Classloading is not that big deal, just try it out using JNI developer guide on oracle.com, and there shouldn't be any specific to JBoss issues.